# Como cargar un menu dinámico en MVC5 desde Entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

estoy ideando la manera de manejar el menu dinámico desde las directivas de razor. Tengo mis catalogos en tablas de EntityFramework con los perfiles y roles de usuario. Mi objetivo es cuando se logué un usuario mostrar un menu distinto de acuerdo al perfil.
Tengo un layout que usaré para todos los usuarios:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("Bodega ", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
...
  @RenderSection("menuDinamico",false)

                        </div>
                    </nav>
```

Cuando se loguean, tengo en mi AcountController:

```
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
   if (WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password,..)
{
 var controllerMenu = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<menuPerfilesController>();
                controllerMenu.CargaMenuPerfil();

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
}
```

Mi controller responsable de cargar los menu:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CargaMenuPerfil()
        {
   //1ro identifico el id del usuario
   //2do preparo un modelo segun el rol de usuario
    MenuPerfil modelPerfil = new MenuPerfil();
  modelPerfil.listaPerfiles = queryDescripcionMenus;
            modelPerfil.listacontroller = querycontrollerMenus;
            modelPerfil.listaaction = queryactionsMenus;
 //3ro retorno un Partial con mi modelo
  return PartialView(modelPerfil);
}
```

Mi vista parcial que construye menu dinamico:

```
@model Mvc4Proyect.Models.MenuPerfil

@section menuDinamico{
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
     @for (var i=0 ; i<=Model.listaPerfiles.Count; i++)
     {
                                <li style="color:#fff">
                                   @Html.ActionLink(Model.listaPerfiles[i], Model.listaaction[i], Model.listacontroller[i],null,new {@style="color:#fff"})
                                </li>                                
     }
          </ul>
```

Mi único problema es como permitir un modelo por defecto desde layout o en razor con mi vista 'CargaPerfil' o en su defecto como manejar ese @RenderSection para cargar dicho contenido

Answer (score 0):

en vista del éxito no obtenido, encontré una solución; cambiando la importación del modelo por objetos ViewData[].Esto considerando que no tengo implementado Identity, por lo que un @if (User.IsAutenticated) no funciona en este caso(mi autenticacion se base en Membership).De hecho omití la parte de "var controllerMenu = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService()", simplemente llenando obtejos ViewBag[] o ViewData con cada lista y asunto resuelto